# Always print multiple error lines

Tags: python, printing

I'm busy working on a tool for tagging documents. I can't seem to solve an issue im having. See the code below, these are 2 functions that are a small part of my code:

```
def runSearch():
time.sleep(1)
#checkt of de lengte van de list keywords groter is dan 0, zo niet, moet je eerst keywords opgeven
if len(keywords) > 0:
    path_input = raw_input('Give path to check for documents(e.g. /Users/Frank/Desktop): ')
    errCounter = 0

    #hier word gekeken of de opgegeven directory bestaat
    if os.path.isdir(path_input):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_input):
            for file in files:
                fullFile = os.path.join(root, file)
                if os.path.splitext(fullFile)[1].lower() == ('.docx') or \
                                os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() == ('.doc') or \
                                os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() ==  ('.pptx') or \
                                os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() == ('.txt') or \
                                os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() == ('.xlsx') or \
                                os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() == ('.xls') or \
                                os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() == ('.odt') or \
                                os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() == ('.rtf') or \
                                os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() == ('.csv') or \
                                os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() == ('.html') or \
                                os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() == ('.htm') or \
                                os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() == ('.pdf'):
                    tagDocs(fullFile)

        print ('\nSearch for keyword(s) completed.')
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("\nPlease enter a valid path, for example: '/Users/Frank/Documents'")
else:
    print('\nNo keywords were defined, use menu option 2 first.')
raw_input("\nPress Enter to continue...")
menu()

def tagDocs(fullFile):
    try:
        content = textract.process(os.path.abspath(fullFile))
        # contentList.append(content)
        words = content.split()
        words = [words.lower() for words in words]

        tagCounter = 0

        for item in enumerate(words):
            for index, value in enumerate(keywords):
                if value in item:
                    tagDocuments.append(fullFile)
                    tagCounter += 1

        if tagCounter != 0:
            print ("\nIn the file '" + os.path.abspath(fullFile) + "' the tag(s)" +  " was found: " +
                   str(tagCounter) + " time(s).")

    except Exception, e:
        errorLog(e)
        pass
```

Every time there's an error passed to errorLog() it print the error 4 times in the error.log. I know what's causing this, it's because it loops 4 times, because there are 4 files, if I add a file into the folder im scanning, it will print the error 5 times. So my question, how can I make it only print the error 1 time? Now it prints the error 1 time for every file it finds.

**update #2**

```
def errorLogOnce(err):
    if not err in reported_errors:
        reported_errors.append(err)
        errorLog(err)

def errorLog(e):
    errCounter = 0
    errCounter += 1

    logging.basicConfig(filename='error.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.debug(e)
```

Comment: what do you intend to do in case a file causes an error? Interrupt the tagging of the other files in the same directory or interrupt the whole process?

Comment: I already have an errorLog function which prints the error in a file, after this it will just continue tagging again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want less lines of code, without classes, you can also do this:

```
reported_errors = []

def errorLogOnce(err):
  if not err in reported_errors:
    reported_errors.append(err)
    errorLog(err)
```

And then call errorLogOnce instead of calling errorLog

Comment: Sorry for late reply, been super busy with other things. However, I did try this out and it seems it still prints it more often then once. See **update #2**. Thanks for helping btw :)

Comment: Maybe if I explain it a bit better: So I'm using a library called Textract. It does not support .log files. So every time it meets an .log file, it create the error, on a different file, the same error will occur. So the error gets printed 2 times, if there's 2 log files. But printing the same type of error twice seems kinda useless.

Answer (score 0):

So you want a logger that never repeats a log of the same error?
If so, define a class

```
class MyLogger(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.reported_errors = []
   def log(self,err):
      if not err in self.reported_errors:
         self.repoted_errors.add(err)
         errorLog(err)
```

And call this logger instead of directly calling errorLog(e) directly

```
def runSearch():
   logger = MyLogger()
      ....
      tagDocs(fullFile,logger)
   ....

def tagDocs(fullFile,logger):
  try:
     ...
  except Exception, e:
    logger.log(e)
    pass
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in a way that I won't need a nother class? Like a function?

Comment: You could also keep reported_errors as a global variable:

Comment: not sure if it matters, but im using the lib logging to create the log file.

Comment: Does't matter. In any case you need to build your own logic around the logging library, to prevent it from logging the same error more than once.

Comment: Sorry to be so rude, but isn't there a simpler way? I'm quite new with python and just trying to implement this seems a challenge on it's on.